# Determine values of $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $(\lambda−1,0,−2),(−2,\lambda,−4),(−3,−2,\lambda−1)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Determine the values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$  so that $\{(\lambda − 1, 0, −2),(−2, \lambda, −4),(−3, −2, \lambda − 1)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Any tips. I tried deconstructing it with eigenvalues and the determinant as equivalent to zero to find when it is not the case. Have no idea what else to do. Any ideas.

Comment: Show us your attempt with non-zero determinant.

Comment: The only variable I got that applied was -2.10092

Comment: How did you get this value?

Answer (score 1):

> and the determinant as equivalent to zero to find when it is not the case.

This is fine: the vectors are linearly independent (and thus form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since you have 3) if the following determinant is non-zero:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda − 1 & 0 & −2 \\ 
−2 & \lambda & −4 \\ 
−3 & −2 & \lambda − 1
\end{vmatrix}$$

You can use the [rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) or expand the determinant along any row or column, right away or after using some properties of determinants to create more zeroes. In any case, you should find:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda − 1 & 0 & −2 \\ 
−2 & \lambda & −4 \\ 
−3 & −2 & \lambda − 1
\end{vmatrix} = 0 \iff \lambda^3 - 2 \lambda^2 - 13 \lambda = 0$$
So you're lucky since you can factor out $\lambda$:
$$\lambda^3 - 2 \lambda^2 - 13 \lambda = 0 \iff \lambda = 0 \;\vee\; \lambda^2 - 2 \lambda - 13 = 0$$
This leaves you with a quadratic equation in $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing when the determinant (of the matrix of which these are the columns) is zero (and then take all the other values of $\lambda$) as you write is a perfectly valid strategy.

The only problem I can see with that is that you have to solve a degree 3 equation. There is a general trick for that (not limited to determinants): if you can guess (or find by trial and error) one solution, you can write your degree 3 polynomial as the product of a degree 1 polynomial (coming from your solution) and a degree 2 polynomial, which can then be solved by the quadratic formula.

Example which is not your determinant:

solving $\lambda^3 - \lambda^2 - \lambda - 2 = 0$ looks kind of hopeless on first sight, but once we 'see' that $\lambda = 2$ is a solution we can simplify it to $(\lambda - 2)(\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1) = 0$ and proceed from there.

Comment: In this case, there’s no constant term so the cubic is quite easy to solve.

Comment: I know, but I wanted the OP to figure this out for themselves...